# how to create backup for stored procedure,trigger and functions of a database in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, backup, stored-procedures, trigger, functions

I'm having 2 databases in 2 different servers(.246 and .252). I need to create backup for all stored procedures, triggers and function from 252 server and restore it in 246 server.database name in both server is transcredit. around 500SP are there in 252 server. can anyone help me?

Comment: So are you asking how to create a backup of just those objects and not any of the data in the database?

Comment: both servers having the same tables. no need to retrieve data's. just have to create backup for these 3 things and restore it in another server(i.e) 246 server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948678/scripting-out-individual-objects-from-sql-using-smo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you have framed your question to somewhat misleading.

You want to script out all stored procedures, triggers and functions from one server and create them on the new server.

**Option 1 : USING SSMS**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**OPTION 2 : USING TSQL** - `sys.sql_modules with sys.objects`

Comment: i did like this only. after these process in save or publish scripts page error throwing. i have around 500 SP in this database, is this a problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to visual studio or a 3rd party tool like Redgate schema compare your can run a comparison of the databases and select the objects you want copied from DB to another. The tool will build a script to recreate those objects in the 2nd DB.

Visual Studio DB chema compare [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833435%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Redgate Schema Compare [here](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/)

Comment: i tried this..Is there any query to create backup for all the SP's in a Database?

Comment: and what happened when you tried this?

Comment: You can also use [xSQL Schema Compare](http://www.xsql.com/products/sql_server_schema_compare/?utm_source=pragmatic&utm_medium=articles&utm_campaign=xsql) to synchronize only the objects you mentioned. (Disclosure: I'm affiliated to xSQL)

Answer (score 1):

I have create following Procedure which goes thru all SP and Views in particular DB (can be extend to Functions, ...) and store each code script one by one into TXT files. Tested ON MS SQL 2008 R2 and 2014

First part Inserting all scripts of SP and Views into Temp table. Then later using BCP utility. If you wish you can can use for export SSIS package and not SP as I did in this example.

```
DECLARE  @File_name AS VARCHAR(255)
        ,@Folder_path AS VARCHAR(255)
        ,@File_Path_Name AS VARCHAR(255)
        ,@CMD AS VARCHAR(8000)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP_AA') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TEMP_AA;
SELECT 
 T1.NAME AS ObjectName
,T1.type AS ObjectType
,STUFF(((SELECT ' ' + T.[TEXT]
         FROM (SELECT SC.[id],SC.colid,SC.[TEXT]
               FROM SYSCOMMENTS sc
               ) AS T
         WHERE T.[id] = T1.[id]
         ORDER BY T.colid
         FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
         ).value('.[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
         ), 1, 1, '')
 AS ObjectText
INTO #TEMP_AA
FROM SYSOBJECTS AS T1
WHERE 1=1
  AND T1.type IN ('P', 'V') /* Procedures and Views*/
  AND NOT T1.[name] LIKE 'dt_%'
```

Loop which goes thru Global temp table creating file name with Prefix P_ or V_ and with suffix as Date in format YYYYMMDD:

```
-- Exporting Scripts one by one into TXT files
WHILE (SELECT TOP 1 objectName FROM ##TEMP_AA) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 
    @File_name = RTRIM(LTRIM(ObjectType)) + '_' + ObjectName +'_' + REPLACE(CAST(CAST(GETDATE()AS DATE) AS VARCHAR),'-','')
    FROM #TEMP_AA;

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TEMP_BB') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##TEMP_BB;
    CREATE TABLE ##TEMP_BB (ObjectText VARCHAR(MAX));
    INSERT INTO ##TEMP_BB
    SELECT TOP 1 ObjectText
    FROM #TEMP_AA;

    --'Setting File name'
    SET @Folder_Path = 'C:\AAAA\'
    SET @File_Path_Name = @Folder_Path + @File_name + '.txt'
    SET @CMD ='BCP ##TEMP_BB OUT "'+@File_Path_Name+'" -T -c -t "Your Server"'
     -- 'Output via BCP into TXT file'
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @CMD;

    --Delete Line From temp which has been procese already
    WITH  CTE AS (SELECT TOP 1 *  FROM  #TEMP_AA)
    DELETE FROM CTE;
END
```

Comment: `sysobjects` is deprecated, and probably should not be used in new work.